# BI Publisher Interactive Template no data found

Tags: oracle, reporting, bi-publisher

Version 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7)

I have created the data sources in BIP with seperate single data set using a simple select * SQL for each data source.
The view sample data works fine.
The issue comes when trying to create a report template using BIP interactive format (xpt).

I create the data table and when I drag the column from left pane in to data table, a No Data Found error is all I get.

It is random since it works fine for other data sources with select * from same database and since the view sample data works in the data source the the chance the SQL is causing this error is nil.

I have recreated these data sources and error still occurs.

Think this is a bug with BIP?

edit: including SQL and generated xml for a data source, I can't share any names though.
SQL:

`SELECT
*
FROM
view;`

XML:

```
<output rootName="DATA_DS" uniqueRowName="false">
<nodeList name="data-structure">
<dataStructure tagName="DATA_DS">
<group name="G_1" label="G_1" source="zzz">
<element name="xxx" value="xxx" label="xxx" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder=""        
fieldOrder="1"/>
<element name="mmm" value="mmm" label="mmm" dataType="xsd:string"   
breakOrder="" fieldOrder="2"/>
<element name="yyy" value="yyy" label="yyy" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder=""    
fieldOrder="3"/>
<element name="aaa" value="aaa" label="aaa" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder=""  
fieldOrder="4"/>
<element name="bbb" value="bbb" label="bbb" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder=""   
fieldOrder="5"/>
<element name="ccc" value="ccc" label="ccc" dataType="xsd:long" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="6"/>
<element name="ddd" value="ddd" label="ddd" dataType="xsd:double" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="7"/>
<element name="eee" value="eee" label="eee" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="8"/>
<element name="fff" value="fff" label="fff" dataType="xsd:long" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="9"/>
<element name="ggg" value="ggg" label="ggg" dataType="xsd:long" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="10"/>
<element name="ggg" value="ggg" label="ggg" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="11"/>
<element name="hhh" value="hhh" label="hhh" dataType="xsd:long" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="12"/>
<element name="iii" value="iii" label="iii" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="13"/>
<element name="jjj" value="jjj" label="jjj" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" 
fieldOrder="14"/>
</group>
</dataStructure>
</nodeList>
</output>
```

error message when dragging a data column into data table:
xxx
"No data found: /DATA_DS/G_1/xxx"

Comment: Can you include the code needed to reproduce the error/behaviour please, it is probably worth having a quick scan of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chandan Vidwani for the help,

The data types in the data set have to be changed from long to double and the error magically goes away. Long can still be used for RTF format.